# Remote Docker and volume binding

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a container in another machine. I configured the host to start with `-H 0.0.0.0:2376` and it seems to be working:

```
$ DOCKER_HOST="tcp://dockerhost:2376" docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
383b188c7110        selenium/node-firefox:2.45.0   "/opt/bin/entry_poin   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                                   docker_node_1502  
...
```

Those simple commands work, but, if I try to run it binding a volume from my current machine, seems like the volumes don't work properly:

```
$ DOCKER_HOST="tcp://dockerhost:2376" docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/tmp:rw caarlos0/alpine-oraclejdk7-mvn ls /tmp/
SomeFolder
somescript.sh
anotherFolder
hsperfdata_root
file.xml
```

The files are there, but, they are all empty...

So, if I run something else, nothing happens:

```
$ DOCKER_HOST="tcp://dockerhost:2376" docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/tmp:rw caarlos0/alpine-oraclejdk7-mvn /bin/sh /tmp/somescript.sh
```

Also, seems like it doesn't even run anything when I try to exec /bin/sh:

```
$ DOCKER_HOST="tcp://dockerhost:2376" docker ps -a | grep alpine
# yeah, nothing
$ docker ps -a | grep alpine
# yeah, nothing either
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you $ `DOCKER_HOST="tcp://dockerhost:2376" docker run -it -v \`pwd\`:/tmp:rw caarlos0/alpine-oraclejdk7-mvn /bin/bash` and go into `/tmp` and verify? It seems to me all the files should be there.

Comment: I just did another test. If I ran this and mount a folder that exists in the dockerhost, it works. The problem is that it doesn't transfer the data from the client to the host as I thought it would..

Comment: I did not get your question. Did you mean, when you execute the command I shared and from `/tmp` inside the container, if you create a file (say, you do `echo "test this" > insideContainertest.txt`), then it would be there in the host? 
I just did that and the newly created file is there in the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up copying the folder to the other machine over ssh and using it there.